# When I clone a mercurial repo I don't see changes I just made to the central repo (after a commit)

Tags: mercurial

I make changes to my central repo (added files), then issue a commit.  THen go to a new working repo, and issue a "clone" from central.  I get everything but the files I just committed.  What am I missing?
THanks.

Comment: Dumb question: Is the commit showing in the revision history of the central repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably forgot to push back to the central repository

```
$ hg push
```